# How to install JetBrains ToolBox in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: downloads, 22.04, executable

I downloaded the **zipped folder** for the **ToolBox** app from [JetBrains' official site](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/). After **extracting** the folder, I clicked **multiple** times on the **ToolBox** **executable** app, but **nothing** happened on the screen. On searching a bit more deeply, I found that no app supported running such a file!

Please **HELP**...

Comment: Works for me. What happens if you enter `/path/to/jetbrains-toolbox` in a terminal?

Comment: @Jos It says "No such file or directory".

Comment: Did you use the correct path to your downloaded executable?

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu, so I actually downloaded it the similar way a file is downloaded in Windows, i.e., in the Downloads folder.

Comment: And so I didn't know the correct path has to be used. I just extracted the zipped folder in the Downloads folder itself... @Jos

Comment: At this point, open a terminal and run `~/Downloads/jetbrains-toolbox`.

Comment: It says "no such file or directory".

Comment: On again trying by modifying the command to "~/Downloads/jetbrains-toolbox-1.24.11947", bash said this command directs to a directory. @Jos

Comment: OK. So enter `~/Downloads/jetbrains-toolbox-1.24.11947/jetbrains-toolbox`.

Comment: It says AppImage requires **FUSE** to run. Fuse is an app or what which enables ToolBox app to run? @Jos

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt install libfuse2` and then retry the command. The toolbox app requires FUSE facilities to maintain a sort of internal file system. I have `libfuse2` installed on my system, but not `fuse` itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me aware that actually, **FUSE** was necessary to run any **JetBrains** App like **ToolBox**; though it wasn't mentioned in any *documentation* of either **JetBrains** itself, or on any other site that *fuse* is needed! @Jos

Comment: Though I see that things go quite easy on an OS like Windows 11! @Jos

Comment: Keep in mind that this is one executable that will run on any Linux system. The only dependency is `fuse` - which the app politely mentions the first time you run it. I think that is not bad.

Comment: Of course it isn't bad that the only dependency is a **Fuse**, but the *documentation* of **JetBrains** should've mentioned in **bold** that for **Linux** installation, this *fuse* is required! *Maybe* it's mentioned somewhere, but **certainly not** in the **installation guide of the ToolBox app**... @Jos

Comment: if you go to "system requirements" on the page where you downloaded the app, it clearly says that the Linux version requires `fuse` to run. It links you to a GitHub page that explains very clearly how to install `fuse` on many different distros.

Comment: can you link to the download for Linux?  I keep getting the Windows download as I'm on WSL2

Comment: If you're like me and running Ubuntu via Parallels on Apple Silicon, JetBrains Toolbox is not able to run on ARM Linux yet. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316372/bash-.-jetbrains-toolbox-cannot-execute-binary-file-Exec-format-error#focus=Comments-27-7052787.0-0

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I followed these steps:

1. Open Console and change the directory

   `cd /opt/`
2. Extract the file

   `sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/jetbrains-toolbox-1.xx.xxxx.tar.gz`
3. Rename the folder (not mandatory but it's easier for later use)

   `sudo mv jetbrains-toolbox-1.xx.xxxx jetbrains`
4. Open JetBrains Toolbox

   `jetbrains/jetbrains-toolbox`

If you can't open the file type `sudo apt install libfuse2`

Comment: Installing libfuse2 fixed for me.

Comment: This is not working on WSL2, on the last command it just fails silently.

Comment: Same, libfuse2 fixed it

Comment: On WSL2 you may also need to `sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev` (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-8755/)

Comment: I hated WSL2 - I ended up dual-boting Ubuntu and never looked back. I get that you may need Windows for some things though. I can't get away from Windows with work.

Comment: Thanks for the very straightforward and perfectly functional instructions.

I am very fortunate that I don't need Windows for work at all. I use Ubuntu and RHEL and sometimes, the Macbook Pro that my company provides.

Answer (score 16):

#### System dependencies

JetBrains Toolbox is distributed as an AppImage (even though the filename lacks the `.AppImage` extension), so make sure these dependencies are met: `libfuse2 libxi6 libxrender1 libxtst6 mesa-utils libfontconfig libgtk-3-bin tar`.

#### (a) Manual install

[Download JetBrains Toolbox from the official website](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/), extract it, add the executable permission, and run it -- it will then copy itself to `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin`, create desktop and autorun entries, and edit your `.profile` to include its shim folder (so you can run `pycharm` etc. from the terminal).

(Notably, the shims don't include `jetbrains-toolbox` itself. If you want that to work (maybe you will disable the autorun?), simply symlink it: `ln -s "$HOME/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin/jetbrains-toolbox" "$HOME/.local/bin/jetbrains-toolbox"`)

#### (b) Install script

There is an [install script](https://github.com/nagygergo/jetbrains-toolbox-install) automating the above process (except the AppImage dependencies), which used to be recommended in the official JetBrains documentation. (It's not there anymore, presumably since it's third-party and they didn't have control over it.)

You can check out [the script on GitHub](https://github.com/nagygergo/jetbrains-toolbox-install), and you can run it by the command below:

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nagygergo/jetbrains-toolbox-install/master/jetbrains-toolbox.sh | bash
```

Comment: The script still works, but it is not in the official install documentation anymore.

Comment: @Samuel Thanks, I updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to start the executable app by double clicking on it, nothing will happen, but if you try to execute it in the terminal. This error should show up:

```
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

This is because the latest versions of ubuntu dropped the maintenance of the older versions of `libfuse`, which means that you will have to install it manually by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libfuse2
```

Here are some links discussing this issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-7534/Ubuntu-22.04-missing-fuse2-libraries

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/can-fuse-come-pre-installed-on-22-10/30970